# How to Update Four Fields based on Count Of One Field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table with counts of IDs; I can have 1 to 4 unique IDs per SourceID.  I created a CTE to count all unique IDs, from 1 to 4, as evidenced below.

[image]

Based on the CNT, and joining on sourceid_revised plus asofdate, I want to update another table with the IDs, like you see in the image below.

[image]

The pseudo code would look something like this:

```
UPDATE  RAW_DATA 
SET 
    RAW_DATA.ID1 = case when Count_Of_IDs.cnt=1 then FIRST(PID) end,
    RAW_DATA.ID2 = case when Count_Of_IDs.cnt=2 then SECOND(PID) end,
    RAW_DATA.ID3 = case when Count_Of_IDs.cnt=3 then THIRD(PID) end,
    RAW_DATA.ID4 = case when Count_Of_IDs.cnt=4 then Forth(PID) end
FROM   RAW_DATA INNER JOIN
       Count_Of_IDs ON RAW_DATA.SourceID_Revised = Count_Of_IDs.Sourceid_Revised AND 
       RAW_DATA.AsofDate = Count_Of_IDs.asofdate
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Update!

I think it's easiest to edit my original post, rather than make a comment.  This part seems to work.

```
select *, count(PID) over (partition by SourceID_Revised) RN
FROM [dbo].[RAW_DATA]
```

So, RN should never be greater than 4.  That seems to work fine, but I can't get the rest of it working.  I'm testing the dense_rank version, and I keep getting an error on this line:

```
cte2 as (
```

Error = `Incorrect syntax near 'cte2'`

It almost seem like this should work...

```
Select SourceID_Revised, ID, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, RN
    Set ID1 = max(case when RN = 1 then ID end),
    Set ID2 = max(case when RN = 2 then ID end),
    Set ID3 = max(case when RN = 3 then ID end),
    Set ID4 = max(case when RN = 4 then ID end)
FROM
(
select SourceID_Revised, ID, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, count(ID) over (partition by SourceID_Revised) RN
FROM [dbo].[RAW_DATA]
) AS Summary
```

...but of course it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like you simply want to pivot out the IDs...

Comment: It's probably some kind of pivot, yes.  I tink I need to do an inner join to the table where I am doing counts, but maybe the pivot can eliminate that step.  I'm not sure...

Comment: Even more such a table design is not advised as long formats provide better efficiency, scalability, and maintainability than wide formats.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. However, i'm not so sure you actually want to update the source table versus just present this (with the final select below). Updating would bean you would need to delete duplicate rows (ignoring the ID column). I'll let you handle that if it's really the desire. I'd leave it and simply present it though if it were me.

```
with cte as(
select *, row_number() over (partition by SourceID_Revised order by ID, AsOfDate) RN
FROM yourTable
),

cte2 as (
select 
    SourceID_Revised
    ,AsOfDate
    ,ID = NULL
    ,ID1 = max(case when RN = 1 then ID end)
    ,ID2 = max(case when RN = 2 then ID end)
    ,ID3 = max(case when RN = 3 then ID end)
    ,ID4 = max(case when RN = 4 then ID end)
group by
    SourceID_Rebised
    ,AsOfDate
from cte)


select * from cte2

--UPDATE  R
--set
--  R.PID1 = ID1
--  ...
--from RAW_DATA R
--inner join cte2 on 
--cte2.SourceID_Revised = r.SourceID_Revised
```

Also, you could use `count(ID) over (partition by SourceID_Revised) RN` but if two ID's has the same counts, then how would you handle that? Thus, I'd perhaps use `DENSE_RANK()` in the second CTE. Something like....

```
with cte as(
select *, count(ID) over (partition by SourceID_Revised) RN
FROM YourTable
),

ctex as(
select *, dense_rank() over (partition by  SourceID_Revised order by RN, ID) RN2
from cte)

cte2 as (
select 
    SourceID_Revised
    ,AsOfDate
    ,ID = NULL
    ,ID1 = max(case when RN2 = 1 then ID end)
    ,ID2 = max(case when RN2 = 2 then ID end)
    ,ID3 = max(case when RN2 = 3 then ID end)
    ,ID4 = max(case when RN2 = 4 then ID end)
group by
    SourceID_Rebised
    ,AsOfDate
from ctex)


select * from cte2
```

Comment: Yes, I think this will work.  How do I pass in the actual table that I'm working with?  I see 'from cte' and 'from ctex'.

Comment: sorry just replace YourTable with your table name (it's in the first cte)